# Having major issues when trying to install Ubuntu, both 12.04 and 13.10

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, grub2, system-installation

This is going to be rather long...

I've used ubuntu for a while now and know my way around it pretty well. But my last install was 12.10 LTS and I used wubi to install it. It ran pretty well with only 30 GB.

To start off, I upgraded to a new PC and the motherboard has the new UEFI BIOS(if thats what it is called, I can use the mouse in it and it seems to be a much better GUI than before)

I now have a new computer and I installed windows 7 first as it seemed to be the safer way, once I was done setting that up I downloaded 13.10 to install and created a separate partition through windows's partition manager as suggested by the wiki. I proceeded to create a bootable usb and it started the installation well. After I got to the language selection page I selected english and it proceeded to reboot and then nothing happened. I tried to do it again but after I hit install ubuntu in GRUB it would do the same thing over again.

Once I did that I thought I should install using wubi again, but once I was done installing with it I noticed that there were a lot of problems with the way things were rendering on my screen, the mouse left long trails and input was laggy. I thought it might be a driver issue and started the updates, once those were downloaded(all 190 MB) and installed I rebooted and selected ubuntu from windows's boot menu. But I got the same problem all over again.

So I uninstalled it by using the wibi-uninstall and decided to use the partition manager while installing ubuntu itself. Again selecting install Ubuntu in GRUB was not working, so instead I selected try Ubutu and then hit install on the desktop. It did not recognize my windows install so I selected others and I made the proper partitions and allocated swap space and proceeded to install. Once that was done I rebooted and now my pc wasn't booting. Even the windows boot menu wasn't coming. I was glad I made a backup of windows before hand so I recovered that and got windows running again. But in the process I managed to create two versions of windows, one a clean new install and the other the recovered one which I am using right now.

Deciding that 13.10 was not working out, I downloaded 12.04 and tried installing that though wubi but it did not even get to the installation screen after I was done inputting all the details in windows and restarting.

I really would love to use  ubuntu as I do all my programming and tinkering on it. I really wonder what I have been doing wrong all this while.

If you read all of this then you are awesome! And Thanks!

Comment: First thing you're doing wrong is using a non descriptive title for this question. Change the title to something useful and attract more people to take a look.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that I did lot complete the titile,will edit it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've installed a dualboot system for others, is that I install Windows first, using small partition. I leave the rest unpartitioned and boot Ubuntu from a bootable USB stick, choose "Use free space" and let the installer care about the rest. I don't use Wubi for anything, and I suggest you do the same. :)

Comment: I wanted to do that, but the installer didn't recognize my windows install.